# Is this true or not?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this true?
If $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of a finite-dimensional subspace $V$ such that $V=U+W$, then $U\cap W=\{0\}$.

Comment: That is the case if and only if $V=U\oplus W$.

Answer (score 4):

You get a stupefyingly obvious counterexample by taking $U=W=V$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, if we consider the subspaces $E$ generated from $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$, and $F$ generated from $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$, $E+F=\mathbb{R}^3$, but their intersection is the set of vectors of the form $(0,x,0)$ where $x$ is a real number. Their sum is called a direct sum if the intersection of $E$ and $F$ is $\{0\}$, or equivalently, if every vector of $E+F$ is uniquely decomposable in the sum to two vectors of $E$ and $F$.